# High execution time to count overlapping substrings

Tags: python, strings, python-2.x, time-limit-exceeded

I was doing [this HackerRank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/determining-dna-health) which basically boils down to counting overlapping substrings in a string. I used [this solution from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970542/4305436) to build this program -

```
def overlapping_occurrences(string, sub):
    count = start = 0
    while True:
        start = string.find(sub, start) + 1
        if start > 0:
            count+=1
        else:
            return count

def find_health(start, end, d, genes, gene_health):
    hv = 0
    beneficial = set(genes[start:end+1])
    for b in beneficial:
        # b is just a single letter, so no possibilities of overlapping
        if len(b) == 1:
            occurrences = d.count(b)
        else:
            occurrences = overlapping_occurrences(d, b)
        total_value = sum(gene_health[b])
        hv += total_value*occurrences
    return hv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(raw_input())
    genes = list(raw_input().split())
    health = list(raw_input().split())
    gene_health = {}
    for idx in xrange(n):
        try:
            gene_health[genes[idx]].append(int(health[idx]))
        except:
            gene_health[genes[idx]] = []
            gene_health[genes[idx]].append(int(health[idx]))
    s = int(raw_input())
    health_values = []
    for _ in xrange(s):
        start, end, d = raw_input().split()
        health_values.append(find_health(int(start), int(end), d, genes, gene_health))
    low = min(health_values)
    high = max(health_values)
    print "%d %d" % (low, high)
```

I've used a dictionary `gene_health` because as the first example in the problem description shows, a single gene can have multiple different values, so I store all those values in a list which I sum over to get the `total_value`.

My problem is that this program takes a very long time and exceeds the time limit on most of the test cases. I do think that this algorithm is CORRECT, since for the few test cases where it doesn't time out, it gives the correct answer. So I'm just looking for a way to speed up the program, and I think the only place where any speedups can be performed is in the `overlapping_occurrences` method.

I've searched for other similar questions on StackOverflow but all of them use regex but regex will make it even slower (I think).

Any suggestions or poking in the right direction will help. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

`overlapping_occurrences` has \$O(MN)\$ complexity where \$M\$ and \$N\$ are the sizes of the string and the substring respectively. You can reduce it to \$O(M+N)\$ using [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). However, looking at the constraints, I feel that even that might not be sufficient - the highest score for the problem is only 50.

Comment: A naive implementation of the algorithm described there performs worse for some worst-case scenarios like `text = "A"*10000000 + "B"; word = "A"*100 + "B"`. `text.find(word)` is significantly faster than `kmp_search(text, word)` there. Not sure what kind of corner cases the actual challenge uses, though.

Comment: Can you show me your naive implementation? It is very easy to get KMP wrong.

Comment: Sure, I'll just ask it as a question here.

Comment: I have a question though. The KMP algorithm is just used to find if a substring occurs in a word. So, if the word is `caaabaa`, then `kmp('caaabaa', 'aa')` will just return the index of the first occurrence of the substring in the word. So if I want to count the number of occurrences, do I have to do something like `kmp('caaabaa', 'aa')` which will give me the first occurrence's index, then get the part of the string AFTER this index, and do `kmp('aabaa', 'aa')`, and so on? If so, I don't see how that's better cause the complexity will again be a product of lengths.

Comment: @SidharthSamant The KMP algorithm is quite easy to modify by giving it a custom start value to search for an occurrence (`str.find` also takes an optional argument for that).

Comment: My naive KMP implementation can be found in [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/158396/98493)

Comment: KMP remembers prefix matches. So if you have found a match, you can essentially start from there and continue without redoing the work.

Comment: @RazimanTV - You were right. I used the algorithm [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-for-patterns-set-2-kmp-algorithm/) and the test cases still time out.

Comment: @Graipher - You were right too about some corner cases. For some of the cases where I was getting the right answer using `str.find()`, they now time out for KMP.