# Naive implementation of KMP algorithm

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, strings, search

After reading [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/158390/98493) to the question ["High execution time to count overlapping substrings"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/158388/98493), I decided to implement the suggested Knuth-Morris-Pratt (KMP) algorithm. I used the [pseudo-code listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) for the functions `kmp_table` and `kmp_search`.

However, when running it on some corner-cases, I have observed that it is a lot slower than the standard `str.find`, which [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681649/how-is-string-find-implemented-in-cpython) uses a modified [Boyer-Moore-Horspool algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm) and should thus have worse worst-case performance.

The specific case I looked at is:

```
$ ipython -i kmp.py
In [1]: text = "A"*1000000 + "B"
In [2]: word = "A"*100 + "B"
In [3]: %timeit kmp_search(text, word)
1 loop, best of 3: 410 ms per loop
In [4}: %timeit text.find(word)
1000 loops, best of 3: 703 µs per loop
```

So the difference is about a factor 1000 for this input. This is probably due to the fact that the native one is written in C and this is written in Python, but I still wanted to see if I did anything stupid here or missed any obvious optimization.

```
def kmp_table(word):
    table = [0] * len(word)
    position, candidate = 2, 0
    table[0] = -1

    while position < len(word):
        if word[position - 1] == word[candidate]:
            table[position] = candidate + 1
            candidate += 1
            position += 1
        elif candidate > 0:
            candidate = table[candidate]
        else:
            table[position] = 0
            position += 1
    return table


def kmp_search(text, word):
    m, i = 0, 0
    table = kmp_table(word)
    while m + i < len(text):
        if word[i] == text[m + i]:
            if i == len(word) - 1:
                return m
            i += 1
        else:
            if table[i] > -1:
                m += i - table[i]
                i = table[i]
            else:
                m += 1
                i = 0
    return len(text)
```

Comment: I'm not quite willing to put ~600:1 to CPython vs. native. Just wondering if explicitly moving `len(text)`/`word` changes anything. The *specific case* seems to be worst case for KMP and best case for BM(H).

Comment: I guess `table = [0] * len(word)` should be `table = [0] * (len(word)+1)`.

Comment: @pgs why? `position` is always less than `len(word)`.

Comment: @greybeard That sounds like the start of a good answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One immediate, fairly significant improvement that I see would be to calculate `len(text)` and `len(word) - 1` outside of the loop in `kmp_search`. This provided a 30%-50% reduction in time in my tests depending on the computer and Python version.

```
def kmp_search(text, word):
    m, i = 0, 0
    table = kmp_table(word)
    LT = len(text)
    LW = len(word) - 1
    while m + i < LT:
        if word[i] == text[m + i]:
            if i == LW:
                return m
            i += 1
        else:
            if table[i] > -1:
                m += i - table[i]
                i = table[i]
            else:
                m += 1
                i = 0
    return LT
```

Comment: but what about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848483/performance-of-get-the-length-of-a-string-in-python-2-7 which says it's O(1)? `LW` might be a speed-up, though.

Comment: @Pimgd I believe it's the function call that's the issue, not the complexity of `len`

Comment: Yeah, I guess caching the `len` does seem to reduce the runtime somewhat (even though it is not even close to the `str.find` time). I chose your answer, because it is a nice optimization to keep in mind, even though pimgd's answer gives a comparable speed-boost.

Answer (score 3):

Minor comments, but...

```
    else:
        if table[i] > -1:
            m += i - table[i]
            i = table[i]
        else:
            m += 1
            i = 0
```

This sort of construct, an else which contains only an if-else chain, can be simply written as an elif-else chain.

```
    elif table[i] > -1:
        m += i - table[i]
        i = table[i]
    else:
        m += 1
        i = 0
```

---

```
        table[position] = candidate + 1
        candidate += 1
```

These statements seem weird, why not first add one and then set?

```
        candidate += 1
        table[position] = candidate
```

Comment: Your comments are valid and improve the readability and even speed things up slightly (who would've thought the simple fact that I'm calculating `candidate + 1` twice would make a difference). Nevertheless I chose Jared's answer because it is more of an optimization and he needs the points more  than you :)